# Duke 'o' Death GTA5 Xbox 360

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Can you find the Duke 'o' Death in GTA 5 on xbox 360 when you start the game with no updates?

Answer (score 0):

### No.

From the [wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Duke_O%27Death), it is only available online or in the enhanced version for PC/PS4/Xbox One to players who had played the game on PS3/Xbox 360.